# adobe premiere elements 12

Tags: video, video-editing

My MS Win8.1 got corrupted on a Dell M4500.  I would love to just run linux on the new SSD I installed and not pay MS another dime for Win10 pro.

But I need Adobe Premiere Elements (linux editors don't cut it for me).
Will Wine run adobe premiere elements 12 on any disto?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: With your current wording "Has anyone found ... *acceptable performance*" will likely result in your question being closed as opinion-based.  Please revise the question.  As far as WineHQ: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1794